# Use Except with taking into account the number of duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables with same columns :

```
ID    A    B    C
-------------------
```

I'm using the command **Except** to have the difference between these 2 tables. It's almost perfect ... but look this case :

Table 1 :

```
ID    A    B    C
-------------------
1     1    1    1
1     2    2    2
1     1    1    1
```

Table 2 :

```
ID    A    B    C
-------------------
1     1    1    1
1     2    2    2
1     3    3    3
```

Except returns 0 row because the row 1 1 1 1 is already present in these table even if he is present in a different number ... here is the problem.

I need to have

```
1   1   1   1
```

as result ... as many times as the row doesn't appear in the second table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `EXCEPT ALL` (which appears to be unsupported by SQL Server, at least by previous versions)?

Comment: unsupported indeed ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select id,a,b,c from 
(
Select *, Row_Number() Over (Partition By id,a,b,c order by id,a,b,c) as Row
from t1
Except
Select *, Row_Number() Over (Partition By id,a,b,c order by id,a,b,c) as Tow
from t2
  ) t
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7603d/1)